# Filtering elements out of a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that selects all the elements in a form and serializes them like this:

```
var filter = 'form :not([name^=ww],[id$=IDF] *,.tools *)';
var serialized = $(filter).serialize();
```

This works, unless the form gets around 600+ elements.  Then the user gets s javascript error saying that the script is running slow and may make their browsers unresponsive.  It then gives them the option to stop running the script.

I have tried running the filters separately, I have tried using .not on the selectors, then serializing them, but I run into one of two problems.  Either it runs faster without the error, but also does not filter the elements, or it does filter the elements and gives me the slow script error.

Any ideas?

Comment: *why, oh why* would you have 600+ input elements in a form in html !?!?

Comment: your problem is not the selector. redesign your page so that it uses less input fields. redesign your logic so that it doesn't need to serialize hundreds of items in script.

Comment: having less input fields is not an option.  I can't go into too much detail, but that is by design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 600+ elements this is going to be dead slow. You need to offer Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) some opportunities for optimisation.

First, consider the fact that jQuery can use the natively-supported `querySelectorAll` method (in modern browsers) if your selector complies with the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) (or at least to the extent of what's currently supported in browsers).

With your case, that would mean passing only one *simple* selector to `:not` instead of 3 (1 simple, 2 complex).

```
form :not([name^=ww])
```

That would be quite fast... although you're not being kind to browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll`.

Look at your selector and think about how much Sizzle has to do with each element. First it needs to get ALL elements within the page (you're not *pre-qualifying* the `:not` selector with a tag/class/id). Then, on each element it does the following:

*(assume that it exits if a result of a check is false)*

1. Check that the parent has an ancestor with the `nodeName.toLowerCase()` of `form`.
2. Check that it does not have a `name` attribute starting with `ww` (basic `indexOf` operation).
3. Check that it does not have an ancestor with an `id` attribute ending in `IDF`. (expensive operation)
4. Check that it does not have an ancestor with a `class` attribute containing `tools`.

The last two operations are slow.

It may be best to manually construct a `filter` function, like so:

```
var jq = $([1]);
$('form :input').filter(function(){

    // Re-order conditions so that
    // most likely to fail is at the top!

    jq[0] = this; // faster than constructing a new jQ obj

    return (

        !jq.closest('[id$=IDF]')[0]
            // this can be improved. Maybe pre-qualify
            // attribute selector with a tag name

        && !jq.closest('.tools')[0]

        && this.name.indexOf('ww') !== 0

    );

});
```

Note: that function is untested. Hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: I might add that I could help in optimising this more if I could see the markup. I still have questions regarding it... like: how many `[id$=IDF]` elements are there, and are they all of a different tag? Is there no way they could be given the same class?

Comment: Well, looks like this fixed the javascript error and filters correctly.  It is still super slow, but I guess that is expected for what it is doing.

I will look into adding a class, or something that could speed this up.  It would not be a trivial update though, so I don't think it will be implemented for a while.

Comment: Why this.name.indexOf and not jq.name.indexOf?

Comment: @Barlow Tucker, because `jq` is a jQuery object and doesn't have a `name` property. `this` refers to the actual DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe just serialize the whole form and do your filtering on the backend? Also, why-oh-why is the form growing to 600+ fields?

Comment: This would work, but I need to do some logic on the serialized form before doing a postback

Comment: Well, I'd try sending back whatever data you need to perform that logic back with the request and again let the backend do it. This way you just do `serialize` on the whole form which should be pretty fast (eg, not on a list, but on a single form element) and then simple show a spinner while the backend hacks away.

Answer (score 0):

use the `:input` selector to only select applicable elements..

Comment: @barlow, i think my answer might be wrong.. i believe serialize only selects `:input` elements by default... but jquery api site is down at the moment and can't verify..